# Array of Objects contains the last one only

Tags: java, arrays, object

I wrote in Java a `notebook` class, which contains properties of a notebook ( 3 of them), asks the user to enter them, and then it contains a function to display them.

The second class `notebookArray` declares an array of type `notebook` declared above. The problem is, after I read a number of elements and then I would like to display them, every element of the array contains the properties of the last read.

**Here are the codes:**

**notebook.class**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class notebook{
static String colour;
static String company;
static String model;



static void readOne(){
   System.out.println("Company?");
   Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
   company=in.next();
   System.out.println("Model?");
   model=in.next();
   System.out.println("Colour?");
   colour=in.next();
}

static void showOne(){
   System.out.println(company);
   System.out.println(model);
   System.out.println(colour);
}

}
```

**notebookArray.class**

```
import java.util.*;
public class notebookArray{

static List<notebook> arrayOfNotebooks=new ArrayList<>();
static int n;
static notebook a;
public static void main(String[] args){
   addMore();
   showMore();
}
static void addMore(){

   System.out.println("How many notebooks would you like to add?");
   Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);

   n=keyboard.nextInt();

   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {

      a=new notebook();
      a.readOne();
      arrayOfNotebooks.add(a);
   }
}

static void showMore(){
   for(notebook p : arrayOfNotebooks)
   {
      p.showOne();
   }
}
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to format the code in your question before you post next time - if your code isn't already formatted, I'd suggest using an IDE which can format it for you. Then make sure your code looks the same in your Stack Overflow post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the static members in your `notebook` class :

```
static String colour;
static String company;
static String model;
```

Remove the static keyword, since you want each `notebook` instance to have different values for those members.

Your methods `readOne` and `showOne` shouldn't be static either, since they should work with non static members.

Answer (score 2):

You have created static variables in you class. Which are causing the issues. CHange it to be normal variable

```
static String colour;
static String company;
static String model;
```

with

```
String colour;
String company;
String model;
```

Answer (score 0):

In `notebookArray` you have a single static `notebook` object:

```
static notebook a;
```

which you continually re-instatiate and add to your `ArrayList`; hence them all being the same:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    a=new notebook();
    a.readOne();
    arrayOfNotebooks.add(a);
}
```

remove the static `notebook` member and change this loop to create a new notebook instance before adding it to the `ArrayList` in each iteration:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    notebook a=new notebook();
    a.readOne();
    arrayOfNotebooks.add(a);
}
```

As others have said the members and methods of `notebook` should also not be static; that will also cause the issue you're seeing.

Comment: Interestingly, it works with the "static notebook a;" declaration as well ( in the "notebookArray"  class, after changing the methods and variables to non static in the "notebook" class.

Comment: Yes if you declare a `notebook` variable `a` in your method then it will override the member within the scope of that method. I only said remove it as it now serves no purpose :)